# MediaCodec Lollipop not decoding raw H264 stream 1080P at 60 FPS

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

This is my follow up question to below thread

[Slow H264 1080P@60fps Decoding on Android Lollipop 5.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999675/slow-h264-1080p60fps-decoding-on-android-lollipop-5-0-2)

On the path of debugging the root cause of above issue, I tried various approach to Decode 1080P at 60 FPS.

- I tried wrapping H264 data into a MP4 container(without transcoding).
  The playback of MP4 with various stock player seems slow(less than
  60fps , around 42fps).
- I tried using native codec samples from Android NDK. Still no
  progress.
- Later I compiles the mxc-vpu-test code from the Freescale Android Source
  tree. With this and using the correct parameters, I was Capable of
  playing the video at 60 FPS.

So My doubts are

1. Is the decoder capable of playing 1080p@60fps video, with correct
   Frame rate ?
2. If so, then why MediaCodec ( using ACodec code internally ) is not capable of playing 1080p@60fps video.
3. I am not sure if OMXCodec is used in this process, Where can I get OMXCodec  sample code to decode my video.

Comment: Follow the answer from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999675/slow-h264-1080p60fps-decoding-on-android-lollipop-5-0-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999675/slow-h264-1080p60fps-decoding-on-android-lollipop-5-0-2)

Answer (score 2):

> Is the decoder capable of playing 1080p@60fps video, with correct Frame rate ?

Totally depends on the device.

> If so, then why MediaCodec ( using ACodec code internally ) is not capable of playing 1080p@60fps video.

h.264 has levels. 1080p@60 requires level 4.2 or higher. If the chip on your device only supports 4.0, then it cant do 1080@60. Why? Money and battery. 1080@60 requires twice the decoding power of 1080@30, cutting into profit margins and battery life for something most people will never notice.

> I am not sure if OMXCodec is used in this process, Where can I get OMXCodec sample code to decode my video.

"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I am using freescale sabreSd board, with lollipop version 5.0.2. I see freescale releases some mxc-vpu-test binary to verify video playback ( using vpu engine directly), and using this tool my video plays fine. So I am really doubting the capability of MediaCodec to do this and need some ideas on how it can be improved